# xcode finding contents of an UIImageview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have created an array of images and they start in an imageview. The user can pick up the images using a gesture and drag and drop them in a separate imageview. They can move them about back and forth and they shuffle and organise themselves and all is well.

But I have no idea which ones they have moved into which imageview. How do I identify which image lives in which imageview. Can I query what is in an imageview?

I looked at tags and that didn't help much.

I generate array as so

```
NSArray *pngs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"red", @"blue", @"green", @"yellow", @"purple", @"orange", @"black", @"white", nil];

  for (NSString *png in pngs) {
    UIImage *draggableImage = UIImageWithBundlePNG(png);
    UIImageView *draggableImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: draggableImage];
    SEDraggable *draggable = [[SEDraggable alloc] initWithImageView: draggableImageView];
    [self configureDraggableObject: draggable];
```

Not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 1):

try adding tag to UIImageView

```
  NSArray *pngs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"red", @"blue", @"green",
 @"yellow",        @"purple", @"orange", @"black", @"white", nil];

for (NSString *png in pngs) {

UIImage *draggableImage = UIImageWithBundlePNG(png);

UIImageView *draggableImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: draggableImage];

draggableImageView.tag = i++;//i  must be initialized 

SEDraggable *draggable = [[SEDraggable alloc] initWithImageView: draggableImageView];

[self configureDraggableObject: draggable];
```

you can identify the imageview by  [imageView viewWithTag:TAG]; method.

Answer (score 0):

To know the the view when a view has been attached you need just to look the property 'superView' so in your case if want to know the view that has inside the UIImageView, you need to have a reference to the UIImageView like:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bla"]];

UIView *imageContainer = imageView.superView;
```

if you assign a tag to your container now you are able to do that:

```
if (imageContainer.tag == aTag) {

    Do something...
}
```